# Navigation is not available inside Apollo adapter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am working on a React Native app. I am seeing an issue where I am able to navigate to a screen that is generated using Apollo graphql query adapter. when I navigate to that screen, I have no access to navigation object. The app is wrapped in StackNavigator and navigation seems to be working fine. ANy idea what I need to do to have access to navigation object?

Below is configuration in App.js file:

```js
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: LoginScreen,
        Main: MainScreen,
        Crews: CrewsScreen,
        Customer: CustomerScreen,
        Reports: ReportsScreen,
        Signup: SignupScreen,
        Customers: CustomersScreen,
        Tasks: TasksScreen,
        Task: TaskScreen,
        Test: TestScreen,
        NewCrew: NewCrewScreen,
        SkipTask: SkipTaskScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Main',
    }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                <Rehydrated>
                    <AppContainer screenProps={{...this.props}}/>
                </Rehydrated>
            </ApolloProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

The issue is with the SkipTask screen. Below is the SkipScreen page:

```js
..
render() {
    const {
      navigation
    } = this.props;
    return ( <
      View style = {
        {
          flexDirection: 'column',
          marginHorizontal: 5,
          marginVertical: 5,
          height: 200,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#1abc9c'
        }
      } >
      <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          padding: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#B1EAC6',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }
      } >
      <
      View style = {
        [{
          flex: 1,
          height: 15,
          marginVertical: 1,
          marginHorizontal: 4,
          alignItems: 'center'
        }]
      } >
      <
      Text style = {
        {
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      } > {
        this.props.scheduledDate
      } < /Text> <
      /View> <
      /View> <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          padding: 4
        }
      } >
      <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 0.70,
          marginTop: 12,
          flexGrow: 0.7,
          width: 0,
          flexDirection: 'column'
        }
      } >
      <
      Text style = {
        {
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          flexShrink: 0.7,
          width: 'auto',
          color: 'red'
        }
      } > {
        this.props.customerName
      } < /Text> <
      /View> <
      View style = {
        [{
          flex: 0.30,
          height: 35,
          marginVertical: 1,
          marginHorizontal: 4,
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#1abc9c',
          borderRadius: 15
        }]
      } >
      <
      Button title = "Start"
      color = "white"
      onPress = {
        () => {
          return false
        }
      }
      /> <
      /View> <
      /View> <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          padding: 4
        }
      } >
      <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 0.70,
          marginTop: 12
        }
      } >
      <
      Text style = {
        {
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      } > {
        this.props.address
      } < /Text> <
      /View> <
      View style = {
        [{
          flex: 0.30,
          height: 35,
          marginVertical: 1,
          marginHorizontal: 4,
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#1abc9c',
          borderRadius: 15
        }]
      } >
      <
      Button title = "Skip"
      color = "white"
      onPress = {
        () => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Tasks")
        }
      }
      /> <
      /View> <
      /View> <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          padding: 4
        }
      } >
      <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 0.70,
          marginTop: 12
        }
      } >
      <
      Text style = {
        {
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      } > {
        this.props.phoneNumber
      } < /Text> <
      /View> <
      View style = {
        [{
          flex: 0.30,
          height: 35,
          marginVertical: 1,
          marginHorizontal: 4,
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#1abc9c',
          borderRadius: 15
        }]
      } >
      <
      Button title = "Call"
      color = "white"
      onPress = {
        () => this.makeCall(this.props.phoneNumber)
      }
      /> <
      /View> <
      /View>

      <
      /View>
    );
  }

  ..
```

Below is snippet of the page where I am navigating away to the skipTask screen:

```js
..

const TaskAdapter = props => {
  if (props.data.loading) {
    return <View > < Text > Loading tasks < /Text></View >
  }
  if (props.data.getAllTasks) {
    return ( <
      ScrollView > {
        props.data.getAllTasks.map(task =>
          <
          Task key = {
            task.id
          }
          customerName = {
            task.customer.customerName
          }
          phoneNumber = {
            task.customer.phoneNumber
          }
          scheduledDate = {
            task.scheduledDate
          }
          address = {
            getCustomerAddress(task.customer.streetAddress, task.customer.city, task.customer.state, task.customer.zipCode)
          }
          />
        )
      } <
      /ScrollView>
    );
  }
  return <View > < Text > No tasks found < /Text></View >
};

const AllTasks = graphql(tasksList, {
  options: (props => ({
    variables: {
      crewID: props.crewID,
      date: props.date
    },
    fetchPolicy: "network-only"
  }))
})(TaskAdapter);
..
```

```js
..
render() {
  console.log("********************* " + JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation))
  return ( <
    SafeAreaView style = {
      {
        flex: 1
      }
    } >
    <
    ToolBar / >
    <
    View style = {
      styles.top
    } > < Text style = {
      styles.title
    } > Task List < /Text></View >
    <
    CrewsDropdown stateHandler = {
      this.stateHandler
    }
    /> <
    AllTasks navigation = {
      { ...this.props.navigation
      }
    }
    crewID = {
      this.state.crew.id
    }
    date = {
      this.state.date
    }
    /> <
    TasksListFooter navProps = {
      { ...this.props
      }
    }
    crew = {
      this.state.crew
    }
    /> <
    /SafeAreaView>
  );
}
}
..
```

The export of the Task screen is as below:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

import call from 'react-native-phone-call';
import {
  Linking
} from 'react-native';

export default class Task extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  makeCall = (number) => {
    const args = {
      number: number, // String value with the number to call
      prompt: true // Optional boolean property. Determines if the user should be prompt prior to the call 
    }
    call(args).catch(console.error)
  }
```

Comment: Is this adapter a screen in navigation stack or is it outside navigation scope?

Comment: Good point. The adapter is in a screen that is part of the navigation scope.

Comment: Can you share the export part of your screen?

Comment: Hi, I added the export of the Task to the end of the post. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

```js
render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
                <ToolBar/>
                <View style={styles.top}><Text style={styles.title}>Task List</Text></View>
                <CrewsDropdown stateHandler={this.stateHandler}/>
                <AllTasks navigation={this.props.navigation} crewID={this.state.crew.id} date={this.state.date}/>
                <TasksListFooter navProps={{...this.props}} crew={this.state.crew}/>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
```

I basically added navigation property to the AllTasks adapter from the main component as in the line below:

```js
<AllTasks navigation={this.props.navigation} crewID={this.state.crew.id} date={this.state.date}/>
```

Then I added the property to Task component where I want to enable navigation as below:

```js
 <ScrollView>
                {
                    props.data.getAllTasks.map(task =>
                        <Task key={task.id} customerName={task.customer.customerName}
                                  phoneNumber={task.customer.phoneNumber}
                                  scheduledDate={task.scheduledDate}
                                  navigation={props.navigation}
                                  address={getCustomerAddress(task.customer.streetAddress, task.customer.city, task.customer.state, task.customer.zipCode)}
                        />
                    )
                }
            </ScrollView>
```

My mistake was that I was using this.props.navigation instead of props.navigation.